# Apply changes or data in XML/Android after swapping fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, material-design

***Hello Stackoverflow!***

I have a problem with changing data in a fragment, and after swapping to another fragment and come back to first fragment, data was not applied.

**I have a button named: `Make Picture Invisible`**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btntest"
        android:onClick="btntest_onClick"
        android:text="Make Picture Invisible:/>
```

**Button `Make Picture Invisible` onClick function is:**

```
public void btntest_onClick(View V) {
        ImageView Powerbevis = findViewById(R.id.PowerGraphEmpty);
        Powerbevis.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Powerbevis.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

**I have a picture two named: `PowerGraphEmpty`**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PowerGraphEmpty"    
        android:src="@drawable/empty_yellow_circle"/>
```

As button `Make Picture Invisble`'s fuction as java code above, onClick, our picture `PowerGraphEmpty` have to get **visible** and **hidden**. So it works successfully **but** ...

**Problem:** In run app test, when I **swap between fragments** by navigation bar or anything, and come back to our main fragment which our button and picture is in there, You can see picture `PowerGraphEmpty` is **not** visible and disabled anymore!

**Question:** How to apply changes, so after swapping to another fragments our picture stand still visible or/and disabled?

*Thanks for respond!*

Comment: What is stopping you from saving state somewhere(fx in SharedPreferences) ?

Comment: You must save the state of the Fragments by overriding the onSavedInstance() method in fragment.

Comment: Thanks @VaibhavGoyal , It's my questions answer anyway, I'll add the answer to this form.